# How to serve serveralias when port alternative is in use

Tags: apache

Under windows 7, I can not use default port 80, so 81 instead.
I configured my httpd.conf, like:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
DocumentRoot "G:/bitnami/htdocs/test"
ServerName test.dev
ServerAlias test.dev www.test.dev
    <Directory "G:/bitnami/htdocs/test">
        Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can only access the site with test.dev:81, but not test.dev or www.test.dev
It seems that ServerAlias do not do anything when port is not 80.

I have added relevant code to my hosts file, but no use:

```
127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1 localhost test.dev www.test.dev
```

How to force apache server URL with port appended? I want test.dev, but not work

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't.  Quoting from [RFC1738, the URL specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

> ```
> port
>     The port number to connect to. Most schemes designate
>     protocols that have a default port number. Another port number
>     may optionally be supplied, in decimal, separated from the
>     host by a colon. If the port is omitted, the colon is as well.
> ```

This means that if the port number isn't specified in the URL, the default port is implied.  For http the default port is 80, so any other port has to be specified.